# Simple 1:1 htaccess redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm changing the domain of a website and doing some 301 Redirects to keep the traffic.

The simple folder redirect works fine, as following:

```
Redirect /dive-sites/ http://www.domain2.com/divesites/
```

But when I try to move single files nothing happens, as following:

```
Redirect 301 /home.php  http://www.domain2.com/home.php
```

Any idea why this is happening? I've tried other examples without success:

```
Redirect /home.php  http://www.domain2.com/home.php
Redirect 301 /home.php  http://www.domain2.com/home.php

Redirect http://www.domain1.com/home.php  http://www.merodivingcenter.com/home.php
Redirect 301 http://www.domain1.com/home.php  http://www.merodivingcenter.com/home.php
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `mod_rewrite` and `RewriteRule` or `RewriteMatch`?

```
# Enable mod_rewrite, set base
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Rewrite home.php
RewriteRule ^home\.php http://www.domain2.com/home.php [R=301]

# Rewrite all other PHP pages (including directory path)
RewriteRule (.*?\.php)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301]
```

Test on http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
output url
http://example.com/home.php

output url
http://www.domain2.com/home.php

debugging info
1 RewriteEngine On  
2 RewriteBase / 
3 RewriteRule ^home\.php http://www.domain2.com/home.php [R=301]    
  This rule was met, the new url is http://www.domain2.com/home.php
  The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect
4 RewriteRule (.*?\.php)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301] 


input url
http://example.com/foo/bar.php

output url
http://www.domain2.com/foo/bar.php

debugging info
1 RewriteEngine On  
2 RewriteBase / 
3 RewriteRule ^home\.php http://www.domain2.com/home.php [R=301]    
4 RewriteRule (.*?\.php)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301]
  This rule was met, the new url is http://www.domain2.com/foo/bar.php
  The tests are stopped, using a different host will cause a redirect
```

Comment: Fantastic, works perfectly with the RewriteRule - and thanks for the debbuging website tool.